# Should I reduce number of stages in this search activity for my app?

Tags: gui-design, mobile-application

I am working on a "yellow-pages" app.

The following search activity in my app will be used quite a few times by the user, as it forms a core part of the app. At the moment, it feels very cumbersome, and it is likely that the user would not want to go through the step by step process each time, especially if they want something done quickly. Hence, I was just wondering, what would be the best way to reduce the number of screens within this activity?

I don't feel as if I am using the space given effectively. I've thought about combining different stages together, but I struggle getting the app to render correctly on devices with smaller screens.

Are there any design patterns I should employ for this type of setup that would speed up the process and make it easier for the user.

**Stage 1**

The user enters their postcode.

[image]

**Stage 2**

The user specifies the type of service they require.

[image]

**Stage 3**

The user specifies additional detail about the service they require.

[image]

**Stage 4**

The user sees the results from their search.

[image]

Comment: The 4 stage search seems too much. There's lot of white space and hence I am wondering if you are enabling autofill / 'search as you type' feature. Can you atleast merge steps 1 & 2?

Comment: I've tried, but on smaller screens there seems to be an issue where the keypad covers the second option (i.e. the What do you need section).

Comment: Is it for the <20% users? If yes, why not prioritize the >80% first.

Comment: Currently it would affect the >80%. Hence the reason why I broke it up into two screens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

stage 1 and 2 could be combined technically. I'm guessing you need the postcode 1st to filter only the service vendors in the area. So have the fields one below the other and display on a map the search results. have stage 3 as additional details or as filters

[image]

Comment: Thanks - what's the advanced option for?

Comment: That's for your stage 3!